# Do gravitational lensing experience Doppler effect?

Tags: dark-matter, galaxies, doppler-effect, gravitational-lensing

I watched dark matter explained by Perimeter Institute on YouTube and they used it as gravitational lenses, they also explained Doppler effect so we know how fast things are relative to us. I wonder if the dark matter that enveloped the entire visible galaxy acting as a gravitational lense would experience any Doppler effect at all? Let assume we know the frequency of light from a source behind the rotating galaxy and I wonder would we see any different as light passes through this lense?

Comment: Are you asking if there is an effect on the the light from the background source (i.e. the thing getting lensed) by movement of the lens (the massive object on the line of sight), or if there is an effect on the light from the lens itself?

Comment: @BenjaminHorowitz: i meant if from the gravitational lense itself only and a single source of light can we tell the direction the thing is rotating?